# No output produced in a TiKz declarefunction

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to plot this multivariable function with those values of `\alpha, \beta` and `R`.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Other users helped me do something very similar but now i have problems with my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
     every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$n$},
            ylabel={$R(n)$},
            axis lines=center,
            declare function={t(\n,\a,\b,\R)=(\n*\a*\b)/(\a+\b*\n)*%
            (((\R*\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*pow((\n*\b+\a),-1)-((\a+\b*\n)*\b*(\n-1))/((\a+\b*\n-1)*%
            (\b*(\n-1)+1))*pow((\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*%
            pow((\n*\b+\a),-1)),\b*(\n-1)+1))/(\a+\b*(\n-1)))*%
            pow(\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*pow((\n*\b+\a),-1)),-\a-\b*(\n-1)+%
            (pow((\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*(\n*\b+\a)),1-\a))/(\a-1)*%
            ((\a+\b*\n)*\b*(\n-1))/((\a+\b*\n-1)*(\b*(\n-1)+1)));},
            domain=1:8,no marks,samples=20,smooth]
\addplot[color=black, domain=1:8]{t(n,2.5,0.5,3)};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Because my output is this:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

And the expected one is something like this:

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Can someone help me find the error? **And also:** How could I reduce the size of the numbers in the axis? And how could I move the y label to the left of the axis y, and the x label below of the axis x? (Just like the expected output)

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the user Schrödinger's cat I solved errors and found a new one, my code now is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
     every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={signal},
            ylabel={equilibrium bid},
            axis lines=left,
            declare function={H(\x,\n,\a,\b,\R)=pow(\R,\b*(\n-1)+1)*% 
  pow(\n*\b+\a-1,\b*(\n-1))*pow(\n*\b+\a,-\b*(\n-1))*pow(\x,-\b*(\n-1))+%
  (\n*\b+\a)/(\n*\b+\a-1)*\x*(((\n-1)*\b)/((\n-1)*\b+1))*%
  (1-pow(\R,\b*(\n-1)+1)*pow(\n*\b+\a-1,\b*(\n-1)+1)*%
  pow(\n*\b+\a,-\b*(\n-1)-1)*%
  pow(\x,-\b*(\n-1)-1));},
  domain=2.1:2.7,no marks,samples=11,smooth] 
 \addplot[color=black]{H(x,2,2.5,0.5,3)}; 
 \addplot[color=black, dashed, domain=2.25:2.7]{H(x,3,2.5,0.5,3)}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\centering
{Figure 1. Equilibrium bid of Example 1 with $\alpha=2.5$, $\beta=.5$, $r=3$ for $n=2$ (solid line) and $n=3$ (dashed line).}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={bidders},
            ylabel={revenue},
            axis lines=left,
            declare function={tt(\n,\a,\b,\R)=(\n*\a*\b)/(\a+\b*\n)*%
            (((\R*\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*pow((\n*\b+\a),-1)-((\a+\b*\n)*\b*(\n-1))/((\a+\b*\n-1)*%
            (\b*(\n-1)+1))*pow((\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*%
             pow((\n*\b+\a),-1)),\b*(\n-1)+1))/(\a+\b*(\n-1)))*%
             pow(\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*pow((\n*\b+\a),-1),-\a-\b*(\n-1))+% <- 
             (pow(\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*pow((\n*\b+\a),-1),1-\a))/(\a-1)*
             ((\a+\b*\n)*\b*(\n-1))/((\a+\b*\n-1)*(\b*(\n-1)+1)));
            },
            domain=1:8,no marks,samples=20,smooth]
\addplot[color=black, domain=1:8,variable=\n]{tt(n,2.5,0.5,3)};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But now the output is rare, why shows twice 0.17, 0.18 and 0.19 on the y-axis? The output expected is from 0.15 to 0.19. How could I solve that?
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Thanks you!!

Comment: First glance: `t(n,2.5,0.5,3)` contains `n` instead of `\n`, is this intended?

Comment: ``! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `n' (in 't(n,2.5,0.5,3)').``

Comment: It is generally not true that you do not need the backslash. There are exceptions like `x`, `y`, `z` in pgfplots.

Comment: With the blackslash I don't get anything in the compiler. :( Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues. First of all, `n` is not defined, you need to either say `variable=\n` (or, simpler, use `x` instead of `n`). Then you misplaced a `)` in

```
pow(\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*pow((\n*\b+\a),-1)),-\a-\b*(\n-1)+%
```

I think it should be

```
pow(\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*pow((\n*\b+\a),-1),-\a-\b*(\n-1))+%
```

At least there is no more error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
     every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$n$},
            ylabel={$R(n)$},
            axis lines=center,
            declare function={tt(\n,\a,\b,\R)=(\n*\a*\b)/(\a+\b*\n)*%
            (((\R*\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*pow((\n*\b+\a),-1)-((\a+\b*\n)*\b*(\n-1))/((\a+\b*\n-1)*%
            (\b*(\n-1)+1))*pow((\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*%
             pow((\n*\b+\a),-1)),\b*(\n-1)+1))/(\a+\b*(\n-1)))*%
             pow(\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*pow((\n*\b+\a),-1),-\a-\b*(\n-1))+% <- 
             (pow((\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*(\n*\b+\a)),1-\a))/(\a-1)*%
             ((\a+\b*\n)*\b*(\n-1))/((\a+\b*\n-1)*(\b*(\n-1)+1)));
            },
            domain=1:8,no marks,samples=20,smooth]
\addplot[color=black, domain=1:8,variable=\n]{tt(n,2.5,0.5,3)};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: As for the edit of your question, add `ytick distance=0.01`, say.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
     every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={signal},
            ylabel={equilibrium bid},
            axis lines=left,
            declare function={H(\x,\n,\a,\b,\R)=pow(\R,\b*(\n-1)+1)*% 
  pow(\n*\b+\a-1,\b*(\n-1))*pow(\n*\b+\a,-\b*(\n-1))*pow(\x,-\b*(\n-1))+%
  (\n*\b+\a)/(\n*\b+\a-1)*\x*(((\n-1)*\b)/((\n-1)*\b+1))*%
  (1-pow(\R,\b*(\n-1)+1)*pow(\n*\b+\a-1,\b*(\n-1)+1)*%
  pow(\n*\b+\a,-\b*(\n-1)-1)*%
  pow(\x,-\b*(\n-1)-1));},
  domain=2.1:2.7,no marks,samples=11,smooth] 
 \addplot[color=black]{H(x,2,2.5,0.5,3)}; 
 \addplot[color=black, dashed, domain=2.25:2.7]{H(x,3,2.5,0.5,3)}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\centering
{Figure 1. Equilibrium bid of Example 1 with $\alpha=2.5$, $\beta=.5$, $r=3$ for $n=2$ (solid line) and $n=3$ (dashed line).}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={bidders},
            ylabel={revenue},
            axis lines=left,
            declare function={tt(\n,\a,\b,\R)=(\n*\a*\b)/(\a+\b*\n)*%
            (((\R*\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*pow((\n*\b+\a),-1)-((\a+\b*\n)*\b*(\n-1))/((\a+\b*\n-1)*%
            (\b*(\n-1)+1))*pow((\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*%
             pow((\n*\b+\a),-1)),\b*(\n-1)+1))/(\a+\b*(\n-1)))*%
             pow(\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*pow((\n*\b+\a),-1),-\a-\b*(\n-1))+% <- 
             (pow(\R*(\n*\b+\a-1)*pow((\n*\b+\a),-1),1-\a))/(\a-1)*
             ((\a+\b*\n)*\b*(\n-1))/((\a+\b*\n-1)*(\b*(\n-1)+1)));
            },
            domain=1:8,no marks,samples=20,smooth,ytick distance=0.01]
\addplot[color=black, domain=1:8,variable=\n]{tt(n,2.5,0.5,3)};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time dedicated to help users, I really appreciate it. I saw that the new output is not the expected so I've found another error, could you help me with a little thing? Now I'm gonna put a little edit

Comment: Now I edited the post, the y-axis has a very rare error :(

Comment: @oldenios I added one way to fix it to the answer. The issue is that pgfplots rounds the ticks, but there are several ways to fix that, I added one.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! Have a nice day :)